# ios 8.1.2 not running on Xcode 6.0

Tags: iphone, macos, ios8, xcode6

Is iOS 8.1.2 supported by Xcode 6.0 and OS X 10.9.4?

When trying to run, Xcode shows a message that there are "Ineligible devices (OS Version)"

Comment: you have to upgrade OS to 10.10.1

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your `OS` to `10.10.1` and install `Xcode` `6.1`.